# Angularjs - check if file exists as object properties

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an array of object that looks like this :

```
$scope.tracks = [
            {
                url: 'https://ionic-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/Message%20in%20a%20bottle.mp3',
                artist: 'The Police',
                title: 'Message in a bottle',
                art: 'https://ionic-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/The_Police_Greatest_Hits.jpg'
            },
            {
                url: 'https://ionic-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/Roxane.mp3',
                artist: 'The Police',
                title: 'Roxane',
                art: 'https://ionic-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/The_Police_Greatest_Hits.jpg'
            }
        ];
```

I had like the properties 'url' to be a method that return a local file if that exists in my folder or the url is the file which doesn't exist.

I have tried :

```
$scope.tracks = tracksFromServer.map(function(track) {
                    return {
                        title: track.title,
                        url: $cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, track.file).then(function (success) {
                    return cordova.file.dataDirectory + track.file;

                    console.log("file : " + track.url + " was found in phone");
                }, function (error) {
                    return track.url;

                    console.log("file : " + track.url + " not in phone")
                }),
                        artist: track.artist,
                        file: track.file
                    }
                });
```

but it is not working

Comment: Whats the error trace?

Comment: I don't have any error, but nothing is displayed

Comment: are you sure that files exists in data directory? did u checked it in file manager?

Comment: the file existing or not shouldn't matter, because if it doesn't exists, it fallback to the URL

Comment: then what is not working? are you testing it on device?

Comment: I'm testing on device, the URL/filepath should allow me to create a new Media() but when I implement the method, it doesn't play anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116681/discussion-between-gandhi-and-hayanno).

Comment: Can you create a plunkr/jsfiddle that recreates the issue? Letting people hack at it might provide some insight to your issue.